# AG-Grid: How to remove the Column Menu

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I would like to remove the column menu. I can simply `display: none` it, but it seems a waste to process and render it in the first place. I can only find options on how to edit items inside the menu [in the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=suppressMenuColumnPanel). Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Either setting `menuTabs: []` or `suppressMenu: true` in the columnDefs. In [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BBgCn8AFjMN4FA3HU9oI?p=preview) the silver column demonstrates the first, while the bronze column demonstrates the second

Comment: Ah thanks I was trying to put it under the grid props rather than column def for each. Just verifying..

Comment: Is there any way to apply this dynamically, after the grid has been rendered? It seems that setting the property after the grid is ready doesn't do anything.

Comment: I was able to get it working with `this.gridOptions.columnApi.getAllColumns().forEach((c) => {
                        this.gridOptions.api.getColumnDef(c.colId).menuTabs = [];
                    });`

Comment: Instead of looping through all the columns, you might try adding `suppressMenu = true` to the `defaultColDef` of the grid.